# why My activeJob test cases are passing locally but are failing on travis cl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rake-task, rails-activejob

I have written test cases that check for the enqueued jobs this is one of the test case 
`test 'task to count enqueued job' do
    user1 = create :user
    user2 = create :user
    clear_enqueued_jobs
    clear_performed_jobs
    Rake::Task['newsletter:general'].reenable
    assert_equal 2, User.contestants.count
    assert_enqueued_jobs 0
    Rake::Task['newsletter:general'].invoke
    assert_enqueued_jobs 2
  end`
locally it passes and on travis ci, it fails with displaying radom number of jobs sometimes 16, sometimes 32. This is the Job for which I have written this test case:

Comment: Which assert fails? I could only guess you are running parallel tests.

Comment: maybe you set a breakpoint, either find out the issue or give us more info and format your post

Comment: @sethi my last assertion is failing. and how to run tests parallel, I know that the run one after another in random order?

Comment: try puts ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs to see what are the jobs. I would suggest to test that a specific job is enqueued instead of doing a count @AmitKumar

Comment: @sethi how can we check a particular enqueued_job? Is it by finding the job in the given enqueued array.

Comment: @AmitKumar if you are able to get all enqueued jobs you should be able to find the particular based on the class name of the worker.

Comment: I found this https://chriskottom.com/blog/2015/11/testing-rails-background-workers/ look at the test/controllers/user_imports_controller_test.rb file.  assert_enqueued_with(job: ProcessImportedUsersJob) do
     post :create, user_import: { users_csv: csv_attachment }
end

Comment: thanks, @sethi your direction solved my problem.